How to pass updated value of an class component state to child component
First of all thanks for you help!
I am developing a page in which I am passing user data through the different components using props.
I get to pass the data from the parent to the child, but it seems to not be updated.
This would be my parent code(I will skip unnecesary code.
    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          UserUid: "LogIn",//this is the initial state of the class, is inside a function that is working fine
          Username: "LogIn",
        };
      }. . . 

//This is the function that changes the state
    changeID = async (useruid) => {
    console.log("User Uid: " + useruid);
    if (useruid != null) {
      this.setState({ UserUid: useruid });<--//here
      let auth = getAuth(app);
      const db = getFirestore(app);
      const docRef = doc(db, "Users", useruid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data().Username);
        this.setState({ Username: docSnap.data().Username });
      } else console.log("no hay datos");
    } else console.log("Primera vez");
  };    
//This is the route I am using to pass the value
    <Route
             exact
             path="/ListaNFTs"
             element={<ListarNftASubastar UserUid={this.state.UserUid}/>}
                        />

The main problem comes when the value of the state is updated successfully, but when I click the button to change componenet, the value passed to the child is the initial one, not the updated one.
I made some screenshots to give an example:This log is the updated state on the app
This is the value of the state that is passed to the child component As you can see altough the data is updated correctly it is not passed correctly

Could you provide the complete code? I'm unable to determine if the setState is inside an onClick event handler or somewhere else ?

@OussamaBASRY Code provided Thanks for your help!

I think that the problem must be that the value of the state is loaded in the component when it is mounted, is that correct?
